# From a 2sxc App View, is there a way to Render another Entity + View in a single method?

Tags: 2sxc

I am aware of the Inner-Content/Content-Blocks stuff you have made available via Content-Type setup of a WYSYWIG and related fields. However, what I am looking for is much simpler, seems possible, but for some reason I am not finding it based on how I have searched so far. Let's say I am already in a View outputting my Content-Type, a "Destination" which ties together Basic Content, Image(s), and a Location. I have a field in the Destinations content-type that is a simple 1:1 to an Entity Location. And yes, I am working in the Content-App. The custom Location View already exists to output the linked Entity by itself. Easy to just add another Content module to the page, but we don't want to do that. What I am looking for is to output that whole View for that one linked Location Entity with a single line of code. Does this exist? I could probably use RenderPage() and pass in my Entity and rewrite the existing View to dynamically handle the passed in Entity (or default to Content as it is now).

So to rephrase, is there a function, API call, that lets me...

```
@...ContentBlocks.Render.View(contentEntityId, viewEntityId);
```

Answer (score 0):

### Some background

The `ContentBlocks.Render` requires a lot of information to work, because it also does a lot behind the scenes. So internally a content-block is a special entity which points to an app-id, a template-id and (zero, one or many) content items. So it's basically a module-definition (each module points to a content-block).

### What you need

Since your entity is only the data, it can't know how it should be displayed without you specifying the template. So `RenderPage` is the way to go. I recommend you do this:

- a sub-view which contains the whole logic and can only be used from RenderPage
- call it from this view
- and also call it from the other view, which contained the original work

This is better than a template which does some kind of automatic fall back, because as time goes on, people forget that it has 2 purposes, and will make changes and only test one scenario, breaking the other.

Comment: But the Content-Type entity is not the only data. I am in a View and simply need to .Render() some HTML based on the data (EntityId) and the View (EntityId) that I plan to use. It seems crazy to recode and use @RenderPage.
 
Is there really no way to get the API to output (or give me back as a string or HtmlString) the Content-Type item in the View that I have already chosen? To be clear, I do know which View I intend to use.

Comment: Razor is a very powerful engine - it just looks simple because everything just works. So I'm not sure what you're trying to do - is it parent/details pages? because for that, there are better ways - using the url parameter like /id/75 and then a visual query that retrieves this item for the view.